# Reasons for Ajax Calls Not Being Made on Mobile?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am running into an issue where it doesn't seem like Ajax calls are being made on mobile browsers. I am developing under the asp.net framework, which includes bootstrap. Curiously, if I switch to desktop view, the Ajax calls work. Here is a modified version I am using to test:

```
var pageUrl = '<%=ResolveUrl("Default.aspx")%>'
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: pageUrl + "/GetWeather",
            data: '{latitude: "' + latitude + '", longitude:"' + longitude + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            timeout: 10000,
            success: function(msg) {
                  alert("SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL!");
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                  alert("FAILED AJAX CALL!");
            }
        });
```

GetWeather is a function stored in Default.aspx.cs. As previously stated, this works fine on desktop browsers, and when I switch to desktop view on the mobile version of the site. However, if I stay in mobile view, the ajax call doesn't seem to be made, as neither the success or error alert gets called, and it doesn't timeout either.

Could this be due to something unusual with bootstrap? Thank you in advance for all of the help

Comment: first thing first the console?

Comment: how is this ajax triggered?

Answer (score 0):

Explicitly set the `cache` attribute of your jQuery `.ajax()` call to `false`, like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: pageUrl + "/GetWeather",
        data: '{latitude: "' + latitude + '", longitude:"' + longitude + '"}',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        timeout: 10000,
        cache: false,
        success: function(msg) {
              alert("SUCCESSFUL AJAX CALL!");
        },
        error: function(msg) {
              alert("FAILED AJAX CALL!");
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. Thank you for the help though!